# Like matching query does not exist - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have created a like button that adds a user to a query when they like the photo, and removes them if they unlike the photo.

The back-end works great! The front-end, not so much.

I get the following error when I try to load the page: `Like matching query does not exist.`

The issue is in this line of code: `like = Like.objects.get(pk=obj.id)`

Could someone please help me with the proper code to display `{% if request.user.username in like.get_likers %}` and `{{ like.likers.count }}` in my html file?

Thank you very much!

***HTML:***

```
{% if request.user.username in like.get_likers %}
    <input id="like_btn" name="{{ obj.slug }}" value="Liked" type="button" />
{% else %}
    <input id="like_btn" name="{{ obj.slug }}" value="Like" type="button" />
{% endif %}
<h3>
    <a href="{% url 'like_thread' %}"><strong id="like_count">{{ like.likers.count }}</strong></a>
</h3>
```

***VIEWS.PY:***

```
def photo_detail(request, photo_slug, username):
    u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
    obj = get_object_or_404(Photo, slug=photo_slug)
    like = Like.objects.get(pk=obj.id)

    context = {
        "like": like,
        "obj": obj
    }
    return render(request, "photos/photo_detail.html", context)
```

***MODELS.PY:***

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

class Like(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name='Likers', null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "CREATOR: %s | SLUG: %s" %(self.image.creator, self.image.slug)

    def get_likers(self):
        return ", ".join([a.username for a in self.likers.all()])
```

Comment: It's pretty much what it says, there was either no object matching the Like query. Does this particular photo have any likes?

Comment: @onyeka No it does not. That's my biggest issue. If it had previous likes, I could get the data no problem. It's the initial like that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that there are likes. Both in the view and in the template. Since the like variable could either have content or not, you could check first in the view. If it exists, add it to the dictionary.

```
def photo_detail(request, photo_slug, username):
    u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
    obj = get_object_or_404(Photo, slug=photo_slug)

    context = {
        "obj": obj
    }
    # find out if there are any likes, if there are, add 
    # to the context dictionary
    try: 
        like = Like.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
        context['like'] = like
    except Like.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, "photos/photo_detail.html", context)
```

Then in your template, you also need to do an if:

```
 {% if like %}
      <input id="like_btn" name="{{ obj.slug }}" value="{% if request.user.username in like.get_likers %}Liked{% else %}Like{% endif %}" type="button" />}
 {% endif %}
```

Though really, you could just as easily check if the user liked the photo from the view.